# How to style a group of <li> without affecting others in the same page

Tags: html-lists

I have groups of `<li>` in my page.
I want to style only the first group for nav without affecting other `<li>`s.

Say:

```
Group 1 (nav)
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>

Group 2 & others
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
```

I only want to style the first group without affecting any others with these CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
}
```

How to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply prepend `nav` as a parent:

```
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
}
```